# Any good jQuery plugins to awesomify my pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, usability

I have a basic pagination system that looks something like that:

```
First | < Previous | 1, 2, [3], 4, 5 ... 100, 101, 102 | Next > | Last
```

Nothing fancy really.

I am looking at various plugins to improve the way the user would browse this, but so far I haven't found anything really new or interesting except:

- http://tympanus.net/jPaginate/ : interesting way of browsing between pages but still very classical in the realization
- http://cpojer.net/Scripts/Pagination/ : totally new way of doing pagination, but the implementation isn't perfect and it's not really usable.

Do you guys have ideas on how I could improve the way my users browse through navigation? Are there any good jQuery plugins out there already doing that?

***Extra points for***: Highly customizable, handling ajax and synchronous requests, original ideas

Answer (score 4):

Check out Paul Irish's [Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/).